# View a repository on every commit

Tags: git

I want to view a repository from the first commit and then kinda just on a press of a button or may be a command ,transit to the next commit (the whole repo).I also would run some code at any of the commits . so could there be a tool or some group of command which could help do so.

I couldnt phrase the question well enough so please do comment.

I also would like to run the programs at a specific commit.

This i m doing so that i could actually understand the design procedure of the developer.(eg .How the whole project was actually put together ?).

I would like to share the README of the project which is based on this idea .

`a code reader which leverages the power of github's commit feature to animate the process of code writing.It also works as a tutor making each commit a level to reach and at 100 % you get a complete clone of the given repo. In tutor mode you can see the next step and then understand as well as write the code. This will help new programmers to learn how to develop large applications and also think in such a pragmatic way. This program , i m more thinking as of a desktop application but would also try to make a web app.`

Comment: The command `git log` has a number of built-in features for displaying the commit history, see e.g. [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History). Perhaps that shows enough information?

Comment: I actually want to change the repository content, so like in first commit a person wrote some tests, so maybe i would run those test. So kind off live view of repository at each commit. like i could see the project getting mature in front of me but not only view those files also run them.

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI I actually want to change the repository content: again, that is what `git filter-branch` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) is able to do:

```
--tree-filter <command>
```

> This is the filter for rewriting the tree and its contents

```
--index-filter <command>
```

> This is the filter for rewriting the index. It is similar to the tree filter but does not check out the tree, which makes it much faster

If your command does not change the files, then you will have visited each commit and executed said command without altering the git repo.

The other command which visit (in a different order, by dichotomy) the commits is [`git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect): it also can execute a command but is overkill in your case.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how can i get to the initial commit using `git filter-branch`. I kind of tried but failed.

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI replace `<command>` with a simple `ls` as an example, just for testing. Then if you fail, you will need to edit your question with the exact error message.

Comment: it rewrote a couple of commits with files which were added. but i dont see how this helps me in reaching to the initial commit

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI It starts with the initial commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a list of a branch's commits by issuing

```
git log --pretty=%H
```

You can then loop over these do a

```
git checkout <hash>
```

which changes the physical files on your computer to those corresponding to that commit. To see the changes done in each commit, something like

```
git show <hash1> <hash2>
```

shows the (colorized) diff between the two commits.

Comment: I tried to checkout but this error showed `fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit '757e97770e50d4b35f88f6336bb************'`

Comment: @GIRISH what about using `%H` instead of `%T` (my mistake).